# Is there any good way to integrate OpenLDAP or ApacheDS servers with JMS to propagate LDAP database modification to another service?

Tags: ldap, jms, message-queue

Is there any good way to integrate OpenLDAP or ApacheDS servers (or maybe another open-source LDAP server) with JMS to propagate LDAP database modification to another service?

Basically I need to have LDAP server cluster (several instances with master to master replication) and another standalone Java application, connected via a JMS server (e.g. ActiveMQ), so that:

1. All changes to LDAP data structure are sent to the Java app.
2. The Java app. can send messages to the LDAP database via JMS server to update LDAP data

I found out that there is a way to set up JMS replication for ApacheDS (https://cwiki.apache.org/DIRxSRVx11/replication-requirements.html#ReplicationRequirements-GeneralRequirements), but I am in doubt whether it will work in case we have a cluster of several ApacheDS masters + one JMS replication node to send all modifications to the cluster.

UPDATE: The page describing JMS replication for ApacheDS turned out to be 5 ears old, so currently the only way of replication in ApacheDS, I know about, is LDAP protocol based replication.

Answer (score 1):

There IDM products that will perform what you are asking about.
I know NetIQs IDM products works well with JMS.

OpenLDAP and ApacheDS have a changeLog that you could use to determine the changes made. 
You could then  write some code to send the changes to JMS Queue.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for ApacheDS, but OpenLDAP already contains a full-blown replication system, with about six different ways to configure it; in other words, you can do it perfectly well, and much more efficiently, *without* Java and JMS.

Comment: Our main goal is to propagate the changes made in LDAP database to main application, and post changes back to it. I read about "persistent search" in LDAP, but connecting it to some message queue bus from the LDAP server start will be more reliable, I suppose.

Comment: @Nikolay Why do you suppose that? I've had OpenLDAP replication running via refreshAndPersist to two slaves for about a year without any reliability problems at all. Why would making it more complex make it more reliable?

Comment: I want is to import changes from LDAP database to standalone Java application to use LDAP as data storage, so that LDAP database can be used by other clients, and all the changes are reflected in the Java application. I can see that there is a number of options to sync several OpenLDAP nodes, but I'm finding a good way to make OpenLDAP post all changes to my Java application as way.

Comment: Why not just have the Java application use the LDAP server directly instead of having a second database? That you have to sync?

Comment: The Java application will be loaded heavily. I want to maintain cache there, since I'm in doubt that LDAP server will behave well under heavy load.